# How to display pdf file inside iframe from mysql database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello im a begginer in php and code igniter currently im working on a project and im having a hard time doing it. What Im trying to do is to display a pdf file inside an iframe,which is stored in database  here is my code:

controller:

```
$data['data_pdf'] = $this->home_model->pdfmanuscript();
```

model:

```
public function pdfmanuscript(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblscipdf WHERE pdf_dateuploaded=( SELECT MAX(pdf_dateuploaded) FROM tblscipdf WHERE featured='1') ");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

views:

```
<iframe  style="border:1px solid #666CCC" title="PDF in an i-Frame" 
src="<?php echo base_url('pdf/').$data_pdf["pdf_name"]; ?>" 
frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" height="900" width="850" align="middle">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Try and open content generated from this statment  <?php echo base_url('pdf/').$data_pdf["pdf_name"]; ?> in your browser and first see that it works properly/.

Comment: It says Access denied..

Comment: Please provide full permission to directory where PDF files are stored.

Comment: Found the an answer
my model must be:public function pdfmanuscript(){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT pdf_name FROM tblscipdf WHERE pdf_dateuploaded=( SELECT MAX(pdf_dateuploaded) FROM tblscipdf WHERE featured='1') LIMIT 1");
 if($query->num_rows > 0){return $query->row('pdf_name');
            }return false;
and for calling it to views it must be like this :  <iframe  style="border:1px solid #666CCC" title="PDF in an i-Frame" src="<?php echo base_url('pdf/')."/".$data_pdf; ?>" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" height="900" width="850" align="middle" ></iframe>